# MAX, SUM then AVG all in one SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Complicated SQL query needed here, not sure if it's even possible.

I have a table like this:

```
------------------------
|uid |lesson_id |score |
------------------------
|1   |0         |20    |
|1   |0         |25    |
|1   |0         |15    |
|1   |0         |40    |
|1   |1         |70    |
|1   |0         |10    |
|1   |1         |20    |
|1   |1         |55    |
|1   |1         |55    |
|1   |0         |5     |
|1   |2         |65    |
------------------------
```

For a particular user, I need to get the maximum score for each lesson, sum them, then get their average... all in a single SQL query.

Max scores:

```
-----------------------
|lesson_id |max_score |
-----------------------
|0         |40        |
|1         |70        |
|2         |65        |
-----------------------
```

Sum:

```
------
|sum |
------
|175 |
------
```

Average:

```
-------
|avg  |
-------
|58.3 |
-------
```

How's this?

```
SELECT uid AS id, AVG(max_score) AS avg_score FROM 
    (
    SELECT uid, lesson_id, max(score) AS max_score FROM cdu_user_progress 
    WHERE session_id = $session_id
    GROUP BY uid, lesson_id 
) AS tt 
WHERE uid IN ($ids) 
GROUP BY uid 
ORDER BY avg_score
```

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: I've only been able to do it using multiple queries at the mo

Comment: How about posting your SQL code?

Comment: Actually, I'm doing it via a combination of SQL and PHP at the mo...

Comment: Do you want _all of the outputs_ in one query or do you just want to get to the average in one query?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  I need this average for each user, in one query...

Comment: The question makes it sound like you desire to get the max for each lesson and the sum and the average in one query. Not that you want just the average, hence my answer and several others addressing that need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use subqueries:

```
SELECT uid, SUM(MaxScore), Avg(MaxScore) 
FROM
(
  SELECT uid, lesson_id,max(score) as MaxScore
  FROM scores 
  GROUP BY userid, lesson_id 

) AS m
GROUP BY  uid
```

or for just one user:

```
SELECT SUM(MaxScore), Avg(MaxScore) 
FROM
(
  SELECT lesson_id,max(score) as MaxScore
  FROM scores 
  WHERE uid = $uid
  GROUP BY lesson_id 
) AS m
```

or for "a bunch of specific users":

```
$uidlist = (comma-delimited list of user ids)

SELECT uid, SUM(MaxScore), Avg(MaxScore) 
FROM
(
  SELECT uid, lesson_id,max(score) AS MaxScore
  FROM scores 
  WHERE FIND_IN_SET(uid, $uidlist)
  GROUP BY uid, lesson_id 
) AS m
GROUP BY uid
```

Comment: and if I must get this for a bunch of specific users?

Comment: Can you check the solution above?

Comment: When I use your method I get: Operand should contain 1 column(s) - SELECT uid AS id, AVG(max_score) AS avg_score FROM ( SELECT uid, lesson_id, max(score) AS max_score FROM cdu_user_progress WHERE session_id = 33 AND FIND_IN_SET(uid, (145,146)) GROUP BY uid, lesson_id ) AS m GROUP BY uid ORDER BY avg_score ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0

Comment: put `145,146` in single quotes: `'145,146'`

Comment: One more thing - is a complicated query like this considered 'bad practice' for SQL database development?  Should I be going about this a different way?

Comment: I would not call that query "complicated" in the slightest.  Look on SO for questions with the SQL tag and you'll see what "complicated" queries look like.

Comment: If you do want to use the third query, for getting "a bunch of specific users", I advise to use `IN()` instead of `FIND_IN_SET()` since `FIND_IN_SET()` won't use indexes.

`$uidlist = (comma-delimited list of user ids)

SELECT uid, SUM(MaxScore), Avg(MaxScore) 
FROM
(
  SELECT uid, lesson_id,max(score) AS MaxScore
  FROM scores 
  WHERE uid IN($uidlist)
  GROUP BY uid, lesson_id 
) AS m
GROUP BY uid`

Answer (score 1):

Here are a simple sample **[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf33c9/1)**

```
select Avg(tt.maxscores) from (
select lesson_id,max(score) as maxscores
from t
group by lesson_id ) as tt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AVG( s.scores ) AS avarage, SUM( s.scores ) AS total
FROM (

SELECT lesson_id, MAX( score ) AS scores
FROM  `tblScores` 
GROUP BY lesson_id
) AS s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this in a single SQL query, although you will need use more than one *statement*.

Most easily, you can do this via a subquery, although the same result can be done via a temporary table or Common-Table-Expression.

(Also, note that the SQL `AVG` function already sums and divides results by their count.  You don't want to do an `AVG(SUM(X))`, as it'll wind up with a nonsense figure.)  Anyway, on to the example:

First, write a SQL expression to get the items you will be averaging, such as the max score for each test for each user.

```
SELECT MAX(Score) As MaxScore, uid, lesson_id
FROM table
GROUP BY uid, lesson_id
```

Then, you treat the above SELECT as a table, and do a second select around it to get the average Max score per uid.

```
SELECT AVG(MaxScore) as Final, uid 
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(Score) As MaxScore, uid, lesson_id
    FROM table
    GROUP BY uid, lesson_id
) AS subQuery
GROUP BY uid
```

You can easily include additional aggregation functions using this method, and as it's fairly standard it will work in most SQL servers.  However, depending on vendor you may have custom-built syntax to do this, such as [OVER and Parition by in SQL Server](http://www.midnightdba.com/Jen/2010/10/tip-over-and-partition-by/)

Answer (score -1):

Everything is possible, it just may be very very ugly. Here is an example of ugly code that can get what you want in a single query...

*PSEUDO* Code Query:

```
SELECT lesson_id, max_score WHERE uid=X
UNION
SELECT -1, sum //done via nested query
UNION
SELECT -2, average //done via nested query
```